# Maxim function nesting in php

Tags: php

I have a problem, when I tried to define a variable I get an error.

```
Maximum function nesting level of '500' reached, aborting!
```

My code is :

```
if (isset($this->a_environmentSupported[$s_environment])) {
        $this->s_environment = $s_environment;
        define('PROJECT_PATH', Context::getInstance()->getEnvironment()->getConfiguration('project_path'));
    } else {
        throw new \UnexpectedValueException(sprintf('The environment "%s" is not supported.', $s_environment));
    }
```

I increment the xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000.
The problem is in the define() because if I delete define() the app is work.
Help me please! Thx in advance

Comment: No the problem isn't with the define, it's with the fact that you don't do anything to trigger the end of the recursion

Comment: There is a solution to resolve this?

Comment: The solution is to make sure that your recursion terminates correctly when it needs to

Comment: What is in `Context::getInstance()->getEnvironment()->getConfiguration('project_path')` ?

Comment: You're in an infinite recursion and caused a stack overflow. If your recursion doesn't have a terminating condition or one that can never happen or that can only happen after more than the maximum allowed recursions this is what will happen.

Comment: Ok, thx...I resolve this problem by use : Context::getInstance()->getEnvironment()->getConfiguration('project_path') where I need